errror "Failed to access the data source." with all REST API URLs
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CFMONqqhEk9jp-HwQLBzs_MuKrNhKfEl/view?usp=drive_link
I am working in Oracle ADF and attempting to configure a REST API for my application. However, every time I try to access any REST API endpoint, I encounter the error:
Received Error: Failed to access the data source.
This error appears consistently with all REST API URLs I configure. I am unsure whether the issue is related to configuration, permissions, or some missing dependency.
Expected:
REST APIs should return the requested data when accessed.
Actual Result:
The "Failed to access the data source" error prevents the API from working entirely.

Welcome to stackoverflow! Please edit your post and include a code sample how you created and registered your REST endpoints.
